# How to change the image gallery format options in a MediaWiki category

Tags: mediawiki

There are numerous [optional attributes](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Images#Optional_gallery_attributes) that can be placed on MediaWiki galleries. Also, when images are placed in a category on MediaWiki, they are automatically displayed in a gallery on that category page ([example](https://www.psntrophywiki.org/wiki/Category:Trophy_unlock_images)). However, I cannot find any way to combine these two observations. Can I apply any of those optional gallery attributes to the automatically-generated category galleries to, for example, make the thumbnails 180 pixels wide instead of 120 pixels wide?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set this using [$wgGalleryOptions](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgGalleryOptions)

Just add this line to the end of your localsettings.php file

```
$wgGalleryOptions = array ( 'imageWidth' => 180 );
```